# getting data from $_POST and Showing specific data in php

Tags: php, html, forms

This may have been asked before but i have not been able to find it.

I have created a dropdown list in a form to show a selection from a database.
I am then sending that information via `$_POST` to another page.
But i am only getting the one result (eg plantID).

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM PLANTS";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());

//********************* Botannical name drop down box

echo "<form name='selection' id='selection' action='profile.php' method='post'>";

echo "<select name='flower'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $plantid = $row['FlowerID'];
    $plantname = $row['Botannical_Name'];
    $plantcommon = $row['Common_Name'];
    $plantheight = $row['Height'];
    $plantav = $row['AV'];
    $plantcolours = $row['Colours'];
    $plantflowering = $row['Flower_Time'];
    $plantspecial = $row['Special_Conditions'];
    $plantfrost = $row['Frost_Hardy'];
    $plantaspect = $row['Aspect'];
    $plantspeed = $row['Growth_Speed'];

    echo "<option value=".$plantid.">".$plantname." -> AKA -> ".$plantcommon."</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";
echo "<br />";


//********************* End of form
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

Is there any way i can send all the data via post or 
can i somehow get the required PlantID from the database and show all the information for that record in a table on the second page.
Hope this makes sense to someone out there :D

Comment: You will only get `$plantID` because that is the value of your `option` tag. If you want, you can only send the ID then query it again to the other page to get the other needed data

Comment: How would i get the $plantID result and show all the data for that record in a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although technically you can, it is not advised nor used anywhere.

Just send an id like you do right now and then select all the data with another query based on this id.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM PLANTS WHERE FlowerID = yourFlowerId` and make sure to avoid sql injections

Comment: How would i complete the query to obtain all the data for that record?